# Typeof returns "number", but logging variable shows string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm passing numerical values from a form in an Angular app, to a method in a service. My unit test checks the typeof the values and expects them to be "number". It passes.

However, when I console.log the values (both before and after passing to the method) they're shown as strings, e.g. "10". Even inside the methods functionality I can see that they're being treated as strings, e.g. 90 + 180 = "90180".

Why does typeof return "number"?

(I've fixed the issue by passing the values as numbers using `+variable`, I just want to know why typeof returns "number" when the type is not number.)

I'm using jasmine for unit testing, here's my test:

```
it("coverageParams.heading, .swathWidth, and .impWidth should be typeof 'number'", () => {
    // Patching numerical values into the form
    component.fieldCoverageParamsForm.patchValue({
      heading: 30,
      impWidth: 10,
      swathWidth: 20
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Method in the component snippet below
    component.createCoveragePath();
    expect(typeof component.coverageParams.heading).toBe("number");
    expect(typeof component.coverageParams.swathWidth).toBe("number");
    expect(typeof component.coverageParams.impWidth).toBe("number");
  });
```

Here's my component:

```
export class FieldCoverageParamsComponent {

  public fieldCoverageParamsForm: FormGroup;

  public coverageParams: ICoverageParams;

  constructor(
    private routePlanner: RoutePlanningService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.coverageParams = {
      boundary: null,
      heading: 0,
      impWidth: 0,
      startPoint: null,
      swathWidth: 0
    };
    this.createForm();
  }

  public createCoveragePath() {
    const formModel = this.fieldCoverageParamsForm.value;
    this.coverageParams = {
      boundary: formModel.boundary,
      heading: formModel.heading,
      impWidth: formModel.impWidth,
      startPoint: formModel.startPoint,
      swathWidth: formModel.swathWidth
    };

    this.routePlanner.plotRoute(
      this.mapService.mainMapViewer,
      this.coverageParams
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on to *where* (with code) your variables act as string instead of number ? It might be possible that you coerce them as string subtly. Otherwise it's possible that they are simply assigned a string value at runtime. Typescript is there only to protect you with types at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I console.log the values (both before and after passing to the method)

I assume you mean in your actual code and not in the tests. You're patching numeric values in in your test so it's really as simple as:

```
let heading = 10;
component.createCoveragePath();
expect(typeof heading).toBe("number");
```

This is true because you're patching the numeric value in.

When Angular acutally runs, the value of the form inputs will come out as strings. You don't get type safety here ... [.value](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#value) is of type `any` so it's coming back as `{heading: "10"}`.

You may want to use `input type=number` in your form since in that case the value *will* come back as `number`. Otherwise you'll have to do the conversion yourself as you have been doing.

You could also update your test to patch string values in or otherwise non-numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Because  the field type is somewhere *declared* as `number`, but it may be assigned a `string` somewhere.

Unfortunately, this is possible. Typescript is converted to JavaScript at the end, and it doesn't protect you from incorrect type assignments somewhere in code.

So apparently, check the data that your production code fetch, it should apparently be different than the one you use in test.

Answer (score 0):

just do a type conversion on the string.

parseInt(string);

Problem solved.

Comment: or use the coercion with unary `+`, but apparently OP already knows that.